# Laptop bricked after installing ubuntu 13.10

Tags: boot, 13.10, system-installation, laptop

Let me explain the situation:

I had windows 7 installed on my laptop and I tried to install Ubuntu 13.10 on it(I completely erased the hard drive). After that my laptop can't access the bios or boot from cd/dvd!. when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or the right arrow key it boots Ubuntu 13.10 but after the splash screen I just get a black screen with a blinking cursor.

Edit:

When I press <kbd>F11</kbd> it boots to `efi` shell but I don't know what to do.

> Edit solution:
>
> For those with the same problem press <kbd>F11</kbd> when booting,
>   when you get into the `efi` shell you need to enter in the cd
>   directory and boots from there

Comment: Please edit your question to add laptop make and model. Have you tried pressing `Del` key or `F2` key after power-up? Also on most laptops pressing `F11` (repeatedly if necessary) after power-up will bring up a boot-device selection screen.

Comment: @Anonymous Please edit your question to include your laptop make and model as previously requested and write up your solution as an answer so that your experience can help others with the same problem. Thank you!